# Mouseover & Mouseout with jQuery problems with a input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

**OLD CODE**

I got a problem when I over my "#search" div then it slides it like I should do, bur the problem is when it slides out it reveals a search input field, and when the mouse gets over that input field it starts to run the mouse out function, I've stopped this by giving a if mouse over #search input with a empty function but when my mouse leaves the input AND the "#search" dive it wont run the animate back function.

Here's my script

```
$("#search").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({"left": "0px"}, 500);
});
$("#search").mouseout(function(){
    if($("#search input").mouseover()){
        return false
        }
    else {
    $(this).animate({"left": "-282px"}, 500);
    }
});
```

What do I do wrong? Or do anyone have a solution? I'm new to jQuery so just started learning :) and I've searched Google and the documentation for last 2 days, maybe its just me that's blind, that's why I need your help :

**EDIT: NEW CODE & JS FIDDLE**

I need to do the search bar different so I just made the code again now the statement needs to be clicked instead. Look here at JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/D7s45/2/

That's the jQuery I wanted to create :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var t, isout=true;
$("#search").children("form").children().mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(t); isout = false;
});

$("#search").children("form").children().mouseout(function () {
    isout = true;
    tout = setTimeout(function () { $("#search").animate({ "left": "-282px" }, 500); }, 100);

});

$("#search").mouseover(function () {
    if (isout) $(this).animate({ "left": "0px" }, 500);
    clearTimeout(t); isout = false;
});

$("#search").mouseout(function () {
    isout = true; tout = setTimeout(function () { $("#search").animate({ "left": "-282px" }, 500); }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Hello Ashkan, im getting syntax error, and when i try it i dont get any over function on my Seach div?

Comment: I have done this method in my project and it works perfectly. I wrote it here, not copied from my project, may be it has syntax error. let me look at it and correct it. i will let you know.

Comment: now try it again. of course i don't know exactly about your project, and you might need to make some changes.

Comment: Problem still the same, when the mouse enters the input field it runs the mouseout function.

Comment: then the children of search div have children themselves right?

Comment: <div id="search">
 <form action="" method="post" name="search">
     <input value="Search our site">
    </form>
</div>

Comment: lets see if this solves the problem, if it doesn't we have to add some lines of code ;)

Comment: Now it slides the search bar out as it should then i can hover the input but a few secs later it will slide back now.

Comment: you can put your code here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) and i will try to fix it. if you want of course.

Comment: I might try thatm ill let u know. i just need to figure what code to paste :)

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping propagation when hovering the input:

```
$("#search input").hover(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Your regular code for the #search div should then function normally.

Comment: Landons, how do i put my animations in to that code, like i said im still quite new :p so dont know how i should set my code in to yours ?

Comment: What do u mean about not perfect but close? the new jsfiddle i made or ? because in that jsfiddle i got the problem it wont close again :(

Comment: Darnit.  I'm new to jsfiddle.  It didn't save my fork at all.  Do you have to have an account?